# How do I avoid reading from S3 every time the user updates a filter on the webpage?

Tags: rest, web-applications, aws, filtering

I am building a web application where a user logs in, and uploads a CSV file with employee data to S3.

This is an example of the format of the file.

| id | name | country | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3243 | John Doe | USA | 48 |

Using this data I want to provide a webpage showing simple bar charts for employee count, along with a filter for dimensions. For example I want to show number of employees by country. There will be a filter for age.

Regarding the filter in the example above. Every time a user were to filter, I would have to hit a REST endpoint (lambda) , read the file from the bucket, and filter based on the dimensional constraints.

Is there a more efficient way to do this without reading the file every time the filter changes? Would it be faster to put the data in DynamoDB and have the function hit Dynamo instead of the object in S3?

Comment: Do the columns like ID/name/country follow a fixed schema, or might every file have a different schema? Can the filtering be performed client-side, or is the data too sensitive for that?

Comment: The file will not be a fixed schema. Every file will have a different schema. The only thing that will be common is the primary key (employee_id) . For example a user from company A could upload a file with 10 dimensions. Another user from company B could upload a file with 4 dimensions. The filtering can not be done on the client side due to the sensitivity of the data.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to quey S3 objects with S3 Select (single small S3 objects) or Athena (single hilariously large S3 objects)? S3 Select price is ridiculously low, maybe even cheaper than your lambda. The results of the queries can be cached somewhere or persisted in a database for later access. After all, the content of the file won't change

Comment: This already sounds like violations of labor law in want civilized country

Comment: Dynamo might be a better fit. But, you could also use [S3's builtin SQL support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html) to filter closer to the physical storage. This should theoretically reduce bytes over the wire (include between AWS services) and therefore reduce latency *and cost*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are designing a simple database query engine, and are now looking for efficient cloud-native approaches to handle the backing storage.

This is ultimately a question of cost minimization, balancing factors such as storage costs, costs of executing a query, and development costs.

Some points to consider:

- Keeping the original CSV file is simple, but requires re-processing the entire file for each query, which might be a bit inefficient if those files are large.
- Compression might reduce storage costs. Decompression tends to be really fast.
- You might transcode the data into a different, more efficient format. For example, binary formats will be more compact especially for numerical data, and allow processing without having to re-parse the file. Data formats like Apache Parquet might be worth looking at. However, this might require that you can assign types to each column, which might be tricky in practice (e.g. phone numbers might look like integers but are not).
- You might split up the data into individual columns or records. Now, executing a query will require multiple sub-queries, but you might be able to perform a query without having to load all of the data. For example with columnar storage, you only have to load the `age` column in order to evaluate an age filter. If you put the data into some existing database, this will simplify query evaluation for you. But since you don't have a clear data schema, you would be limited to non-relational databases like document databases, or would have to use an inefficient EAV design.

I suspect that your volume of data is very low (only a couple of GB), that individual documents are fairly small (a couple of MB), and that your rate of queries is very low (only a couple of thousands of requests per day), so that your storage-related costs are in the cents-per-month region where significant optimization is infeasible. However, development costs are orders of magnitude larger, so that more complicated approaches are likely to be uneconomical. If you're looking for faster processing with moderate development effort, a sensible initial step would be to pre-process the uploaded data into a compressed binary data format like Parquet.